# Howto paint a popup with image beside a component being positioned in a relative layout manager?

Tags: java, swing

A have a list with small thumbnails and want to show a fancy tooltip with a larger version of the image of the thumbnail left to the thumbnail if one hovers with the mouse over the thumbnail. If one drags the mouse down to the next list element the old tooltip should disappear and a new tooltip next to the new cell should appear.

Unlike the existing text tooltip `javax.swing.JComponent.setToolTipText(String)` my fancy tooltip should always be displayed left of the current column. The problem is, that this is a very complex relative layout I cannot change for this. The fancy tooltip should appear above all other components like the real tooltip does too, i.e. I cannot reserve some free space for it.

I took a look in the implemenation of the real tooltip and think about something like getting the absolute coordinates of the mouse `mouseEvent.getX()` and subtracting the position inside the thumbnail to get the right corner of my fancy tooltip. Is it possible to get the coordinates of the mouse event inside the component where the listener is registered? Any better ideas for my needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought `java.awt.event.MouseEvent.getX()` is the absolute point, but thats `java.awt.event.MouseEvent.getXOnScreen()`, i.e. this is already the answer...

Comment: everything depends of 1. how thumbnail is painted 2. if you would need coordinates from contianer (SwingUtilities.convertXxx) or not